# Input mask for chainage/stationing numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm designing a website that requires the input of chainage/stationing numbers, which are regularly used in engineering (they identify the position of something along a highway or pipeline path for example).

They are formatted as following:

`E 9+99.99`

`E` is always present and shouldn't be actually typed in by the user, but would be nice if it appears in the input field (like the currency symbol). The number should be entered right-to-left, so as the user types `159` it formats as `E 0+01.59`, `00000` gives `E 0+00.00`, `150957` gives `E 15+09.57`, `19581802` gives `E 1958+18.02`

Can someone please help me with masking this? (preferably without additional libraries, but if it's not possible with standard HTML/jQuery/Bootstrap, that's ok too).

**EDIT:**

Found the solution. The key was setting `numericInput` to `true`. Here's the jQuery code for the mask:

https://jsfiddle.net/1hjfa2g7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. The key was setting numericInput to true. Here's the jQuery code for the mask:

https://jsfiddle.net/1hjfa2g7/

```
$("#teste").inputmask({
mask: "E 9{1,}+99.99",
numericInput: true,
placeholder: "0",
});
```